# Android fragments fun with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a ViewPager in my app. There are three fragments inside the PageAdapter that is set in the ViewPager. All works perfectly fine and I can switch between all three fragments. I have 3 buttons that allow me to switch between adapters 1 to 3. The problem is noticed when I click buttons 1 and 3 at the same time. Here's what happens:

```
Fragment 1     -     Fragment 3

                    onAttach
                    onViewCreated
                    onResume
  onPause
  onAttach
  onViewCreated
  onResume
  onPause
```

As you can see from above, the second fragment is never paused and therefore never resumed. Both fragments modify the same recycler view onResume so with the behaviour above I end up with the incorrect state of my recycler view.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A ViewPager loads (by default) the current page, the previous page and the next page, since you have only 3 pages the second fragment is always resumed.

the solution is to set up a OnPageChangeListener and modify the recycler view in onPageSelected instead in onResume

Comment: is that the only solution? I don't have access to my viewpager from inside the fragments and they are inside a library module where my viewpager is in the app

Comment: actually, thinking about it, I am not sure that you are correct. By clicking through my fragments 1 to 3 to 1 in a slower speed, everything works just fine. It's when the clicks are so fast one after another, that's where I see one of the fragments not stopping and therefore not resuming. Your suggestion would probably fix the issue but your explanation would be relevant only if my clicks were 1 - 2 - 1 not 1 - 3 - 1 as only the next fragment is kept in the viewpager